# with jQuery, how do I properly format dynamically created div css

Tags: jquery, append

I think the class="snowflakes" aria-hidden="true is the problem but i'm not sure.

```
(function($){$(function(){

$(".x-navbar-wrap").append("<div class="snowflakes" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="snowflake">❆</div>
        <div class="snowflake">❆</div>
        <div class="snowflake">❆</div>
        <div class="snowflake">❆</div></div>" 
          ) 
        });}(jQuery));
```

I tried this as well.

```
(function($){$(function(){

var html = '<div class="snowflakes" aria-hidden="true">' + 
           '<div class="snowflake">❆</div>' + 
               '<div class="snowflake">❆</div>' +
               '<div class="snowflake">❆</div>' +
               '<div class="snowflake">❆</div>' +
               '<div class="snowflake">❆</div>' +
           '</div>';
$(".x-navbar-wrap").append(html);


});}(jQuery));
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing a document ready inside an IIFE?  A document ready already functions as an IIFE.

Comment: The issue with your first snippet is the lack of escaping the internal `"` for the attributes.  Since you started the string with double quotes, they terminate the string.  Either escape them, or use single quotes for the attributes.  Also normal strings do not like new line characters.  If you want to use newlines, you will either have to escape the new lines with a `\` at the end of each string, use concatenation, or a template literal (which do allow newlines)

Comment: Not sure what was wrong but here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xa3n5vsh/

Comment: Also you have invalid HTML.  You have more `</div>` than you do `<div>`

Comment: @Taplar So I'm trying to  using document ready is because i'm running this in a wordpress theme, and it seems to load jQuery after the code in the page and gives an error.   and so if I add the code to the theme php it runs on top of everything and i don't want that :)

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I'm saying.  These two things do the same thing: https://jsfiddle.net/35r1s9un/1/

Comment: @DorababuMeka  yours works perfectly, Ive add some of the css from the source im trying https://jsfiddle.net/y7hbn2p0/1/  but when I try it on my site its not working. must be something with my wordpress theme.  thank you for your help!

Comment: `AbdD` is your wordpress  live if so can u share the link

Comment: thanks @taplar that's good to know! but i'm still getting an error so I thing it something to do with my WP theme. thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you have two `</div>` at the end of each snowflake div.

Try this

```
(function($){$(function(){

divhtml = 
   "<div class='snowflakes' aria-hidden='true'>
        <div class='snowflake'>❆</div>
        <div class='snowflake'>❆</div>
        <div class='snowflake'>❆</div>
        <div class='snowflake'>❆</div>
 </div>" ;
$(".x-navbar-wrap").append(divhtml)});}(jQuery));
```

If it doesn't not work try printing the values before and after append

```
console.log("divhtml: ",divhtml);
console.log("wrap: ",$(".x-navbar-wrap"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working now! thanks everyone!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var html = '<div class="snowflakes" aria-hidden="true">' +
  '<div class="snowflake">❆</div></div>' +
  '<div class="snowflake">❆</div></div>' +
  '<div class="snowflake">❆</div></div>' +
  '<div class="snowflake">❆</div></div>' +
  '<div class="snowflake">❆</div></div>' +
  '</div>';
$("#banner-message").append(html);

 });
```